# What is the difference between a Blend and Single Origin coffee?

Tags: coffee-blends

I wanted to know the difference between blend and origin coffee.

Answer (score 3):

*Many of us continuously discuss origins on this site. I searched through the site, interestingly cannot find a short, precise definition.*

Sometimes, **variety** is confused with single origin. So,  I would like to start with this.

Taxonomically, Coffea genus has several species and we consume three of them as the *coffee* drink. These three species have several **varieties**. They may be thought as varieties of dog from a biological perspective. Same species, several properties.

For coffee though, the variety is not the only criteria that affects the quality of a bean. Cultivation, climate, soil, irrigation, harvesting, drying and peeling the fruit from the bean,  drying the bean are all affect the bean quality. So, if you have a specific *variety* and also you can guarantee the region and the aforementioned process is stable for a batch of beans, you call them **single origin** beans.

**Blends** are "blends" of several single origin coffee beans to produce the flavor characteristics of more than one single origin coffee. For a recent related post on blends please check this:

- [What are the basics of creating an espresso blend?](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/4175/what-are-the-basics-of-creating-an-espresso-blend/4176#4176)